# firebase console not showing my App Crash report

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I added firebase crashlytics to my app before two days ago .
Our app yesterday 10 times crashed this report i saw today in my play 
console. But my firebase console not showing this data. what is the reason?

Firebase console now  showing me progress bar continues, but is not showing any report.

At the time of adding firebase crashlytics to project i followed steps from official documentation from https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android
[image]

Comment: please don't assume everyone on here is male, there's no need to add `sir` or any pronoun to your question

Comment: how much time take to show crash report

Comment: can you give me answer

Comment: I am facing the same problem today. @AjayPawar are you able to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Crash reports are uploaded almost in real-time after your app crashes and relaunches. If you are still unable to see your crash reports, then likely your Crashlytics integration is off.

If you followed all of the documentation correctly that you linked, then you would need to contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/crashlytics) so they could take a look at your gradle files, and how you're calling Crashlytics in your app.